# Is it possible to stack dryers?

Tags: dryer

Is it possible to stack two dryers?  Ideally, I would like to have two dryers for my washing machine, but space is limited.

Comment: If the dryers are stacking models you should be able to but check with the manufacturer. The difficult part is making sure you have enough gas lines (or electric) and separate vents to the outside. You can't just T the vents together.

Answer (score 1):

The stacking kits I have seen would work equally well for two dryers.  The washer needs to be on the bottom because of weight and vibration: the dryer on top, so you're fine.

Separate vents are required, else exhaust air from one dryer will enter room through the other dryer.